# Can't load certain sites on phone over Wi-Fi

Tags: wi-fi

When my phone is connected to Wi-Fi, certain sites won't load, especially https://www.nytimes.com/; Chrome's progress indicator shows a little bit of progress, but never gets past that. Other sites are fine.

Various notes:

- If I turn off Wi-Fi while it's in this state, I get ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED ("This site can't be reached"). So my assumption is that the progress indicator's little bit of progress is just because of successful DNS lookup, not because it's actually managed to connect to the site.
- This issue is specific to phone + Wi-Fi:

  - This issue does *not* occur when I disconnect from Wi-Fi and let my phone use mobile data.
  - This issue does *not* occur on my laptop (which uses the same Wi-Fi network).
  - This issue occurs on both my own Wi-Fi network and my sister's; but we both have the same ISP, so that may not be a fully independent test.
  - This issue occurs in both Chrome and Firefox, and seems to affect other apps that connect to those sites.
- *But*, interestingly:

  - In the case of NYTimes.com, it seems to bear some relation to cookies, in that it works in incognito mode until I log in. But logging *out* does *not* fix it (perhaps because it leaves other cookies?).
  - Twitter (https://mobile.twitter.com/) sometimes loads successfully (albeit slowly), sometimes not. Twitter has a lot of local storage stuff (it shows some of its page boilerplate even when I have no Internet at all), so I'm guessing that this has to do with dynamically choosing different backends, some of which I can connect to and some not? (But that's just a guess.)
- This is pretty consistently the case. The only exception I can remember is that the first time I tried loading NYTimes.com in incognito mode, it worked immediately afterward outside incognito mode as well.
- This has been the case for about a day and a half.
- I tried changing DNS settings (first to use Google Private DNS, then to use Cloudflare); no effect.
- I'm running Android version 9, moto x<sup>4</sup>, google_fi.

Comment: To anyone who might be coming across this question in the future with the same issue: I still don't know what the issue was, but it suddenly resolved itself yesterday (about four days after it started). All the affected sites are OK again now.

Comment: Addendum: the issue recurred from 2020-09-30 to 2020-10-09, with the same symptoms as before. So, although the issue eventually resolved itself both times, I'm still seeking understanding and a solution.